# error You need to supply at least one validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my environment is ruby1.9.3+rails3.2.8+passenger.

error: You need to supply at least one validation

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :url, :tags_attributes, :published, :category_id

  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :dependent => :destroy

  belongs_to :category

  validates :content, :presence => true
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :url,   :presence => true
  validates :tags_attributes, :presence => true
  validates :published, :presence => true
  validates :category_id, :presence => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => true,
         :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k,v| v.blank? } }


  scope :published, where(:published => true)
end
```

my controller is

```
class Admin::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController

  uses_tiny_mce(:options => AppConfig.default_mce_options, :only => [:new, :edit])

  def index
    page = params[:page]
    if page == nil
      page = 1
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h2>Post list</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Updated</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.category.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.created_at.localtime.to_s(:db) %></td>
    <td><%= post.updated_at.localtime.to_s(:db) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete',[:admin, post], :method => :delete, :confirm => 'are you sure?' %></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<br/>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
<br/>
<%= link_to 'New Post', new_admin_post_path %>
```

i think it has matter with rails_tiny_mce.
before i rails plugin install it, validates is ok under my write.
but after i install rails_tiny_mce, the error is display.

my site is `http://42.121.5.68/admin/posts.`

when i update model to

```
validates [:content, :title], :on => :save, :allow_blank => false,
            :presence => true, :length => { :in => 10..200 }
```

error is Unknown validator: 'OnValidator'

Comment: That's not enough information. What action are you performing to see this error? Does it appear in the browser or a log file?

Comment: posts/index, when i use validate replace validates, the error is disappar, the page is ok. but validate do not work.

Comment: ` validates(*attributes)
          defaults = attributes.extract_options!
          validations = defaults.slice!(*_validates_default_keys)
  
          raise ArgumentError, "You need to supply at least one attribute" if attributes.empty?
         raise ArgumentError, "You need to supply at least one validation" if validations.empty?
 `

Comment: Sorry, i have added them in my question.

Comment: I looked at your site and the error is in `app/models/post.rb`, not in `comment.rb`. Please show us your `Post` model instead of `Comment`. Try my suggestion below in your `Post` model too.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
:length => 10..200
```

it should be:

```
:length => { :in => 10..200 }
```

See [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#length).

Besides `:length => { :in => 10..200 }` already makes sure that the field is not empty, so you might as well get rid of `:presence => true`:

```
validates :content, :title, :length => { :in => 10..200 }
```

Comment: validates :title, :length => { :in => 10...200 }

Comment: You used two dots, right? `:in => 10..200`, not three. Then I don't know what's wrong. Please show relevant controller and view code.

Answer (score 1):

you should write like this **validates** instend of **validate**